# Increasing image loading speed on raspberry pi web browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, raspberry-pi3, browser-cache

I am in the final stages of developing a custom point of sale system that runs in a web browser. There are categories, subcategories and products. When you click on a category it shows the subcategories and then when you click on a subcategory, it shows the products. Each of these elements has a picture, a price, a title and some other details. There is a back button that allows the user to navigate back to the parent element (ex subcategories -> categories) and also a home button to return to the page that lists all of the categories.

All of this data is retrieved by a post request to the main server. The page starts by only displaying ~30 items; As the page is scrolled, it loads more items. When testing on a regular computer the images seem to load quickly and it is not really a problem. However, when running it on a raspberry pi, the children images load very slowly the first time an element is clicked (ex. a subcategory is clicked, its product's image's load slowly). But, when the page is navigated back to its parent element, and then back to the child again, the images are all loaded already.

Because of how the system is setup, cached images are not saved between browser sessions. The browser is launched as a clean session using Selenium, as it has USB devices interacting with it via python such as a scanner and a scale.

I have tried a few methods to try to cache the images. One method was loading all the images via javascript and then for each of their onload's they deleted themselves (this did not work). I also tried creating a loading page where all the images would be displayed before going to the P.O.S. system's main menu (this did not work either).

If anyone had any other ideas how images could be cached or loaded faster it would be appreciated.

Comment: faster network and/or smaller images

Comment: It is all on a local network. It doesn't go over the internet. Also the images are already not that big. I cannot make them smaller or the cashier will not be able to see it.

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue with `Selenium` on the pi being slow

Comment: I don't believe Selenium causes much of an issue itself. I believe it is something with the way the caching works when a new browser instance is created via selenium.

Comment: have you tried using something other than selenium? or is that just a "gut feel" or "wishful thinking"?

Comment: Once the homepage is open, and a user browses to a category -> subcategory and then all of the images load. If the user goes back to the homepage and then goes through and selects the previously selected category/subcategory, the images will load instantly. This is why I don't think it can really be an issue of just using selenium, but how selenium works with caching (how it creates a new instance of the browser on each launch). The idea for this system is each day a new browser instance will be used and thus the caching will not save across each day.